# What is the Objective-C data type to hold a void*/pointer?

Tags: objective-c, pointers

I'm calling a C method which returns a pointer or 'handle' to a resource.  I just need to hold the void* in order to pass it in again later.

In .NET, I might use IntPtr.  The only different between IntPtr and just an int--other than making the pointer a more strongly typed variable--is that IntPtr is automatically the size of the platform (32 or 64 bits).  I'm looking for the same thing in Objective-C.

Is there some equivalent way to wrap a pointer in Objective-C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you looked at NSValue's `+ (NSValue *)valueWithPointer:(const void *)aPointer`?

Comment: If I was to use this approach, whats the best way to get void* back out of the NSValue?

Comment: In the end, this method did not work for me since, as the docs explain, this method does not copy the contents of aPointer.

Comment: But as the docs explain on the second half of the sentence, so you must not to free the memory at the pointer destination while the NSValue object exists.  Did you free it?  If you didn't, the contents should be there unless the function/method that returns your void* frees it later on, which in that case you would have to copy the contents of your pointer.

Comment: Yes, I expect the memory to be freed at a later point.  I expect a boxing operation to perform a copy--not a pointer to the original data.  So this took me by surprise when I read it!

Answer (score 4):

Since Objective-C is a superset of C, you can simply use `void *`.

Comment: I was initially hoping for something prefixed with 'NS'.

Comment: Hmm, might have been better if you'd said so in the question :) Anyway, in that case I would suggest NSValue as @theAmateurProgrammer pointed out.